# How to connect to wifi when it disconnected?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, cmd.exe

Sometimes wifi disconnected. How to connect to wifi automatically? I use Windows10.
I prefer using cmd, what is the command?

Answer (score 0):

No need to set a command for this . you are using window 10. when you connect to the wifi there is an option check option for **connect automatically**. check this option so whenever your wifi disconnect you will be automatically connected to that network immediately.